# Is "Get well soon" a cliché?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

Some say clichés are over-used terms. Are the following sentences cichés? If not, why?

> Get well soon!

> Wishing you a speedy recovery

> I hope you recover quickly

Comment: Some people will give you the impression that incorporating features such as *cliches, ambiguity, redundancy* is somehow ***undesirable***, but it's not. And in fact language wouldn't work at all if it didn't primarily consist of re-using the same symbols (individual words *and* idiomatically-established expressions) again and again. You might say the actual *word* "cliche" has negative overtones, but not the phenomenon itself.

Comment: Can I infer that you do take those sentences to be cichés?

Comment: Certainly not! But what you *can* take from my comment is I don't think "cliche" (accented or not) is a particularly useful term for non-native speakers in the first place.

Comment: Are they platitudes?

Comment: You've been around here long enough to know that's not really a fair question. Whether some utterance is truly "heartfelt" or not depends primarily on the *context in which it's said*, not the words themselves. Most of the time, *Have a nice day* from a McDonalds server is likely to be an almost meaningless platitude, but if it's from your mother waving you off as you head out to the beach for the day, she probably means it.

Answer (score 3):

These are not cliches. A cliche is an expression that has been overused to the extent that it loses its original meaning - but some expressions bear repetition and their meaning does not change. You wouldn't say that "good morning" is a 'cliche', and yet people say it every single day. "Get well soon", and your other examples, are standard things to say to someone who is ill, as common as any greeting.

If anything these are more like examples of a **platitude** than a cliche - something that one says to conform to a social norm, but perhaps without meaning. Of course, this depends on who is saying it, and to whom. If a close friend or family member wished you to "get well soon", you would think they were sincere. If someone you barely knew said it, you might think they were just saying it to be polite. But when anyone takes the time to formulate a more personal response, it usually is an indicator that they are more genuinely moved to make the expression.

Comment: The Oxford American Dictionary defines cliché as "a phrase or opinion that is overused and betrays a lack of original thought." That means a cliché may retain the original meaning.

Comment: To be fair, the definitions of cliche and platitude are very close in some dictionaries. But I'm confident of their usage in British English. Cliche tends to be used more for concepts and extended dialogue. Meaningless words of comfort would normally be referred to as "platitudes". Still, my argument is that these expressions are not normally either, unless there is reason to think the person is insincere.